# Java How to chain with Math class

Tags: java, method-chaining

I am at the very basics of learning Java, I have tried searching for this answer but maybe I do not know what I am searching for. 
I want to perform multiple operations on a number, so far the only way I know how to do that is the have intermediate variables with operations performed one at a time. This can't be the best way. The following is code in my main method that I would love to have work:

```
  double sqrtAbsInput = promptForDouble("I can get the square root of the absolute value.");
  double sqrtAbsOutput = sqrtAbsInput.Math.abs().sqrt();
  System.out.println(sqrAbsOutput);
```

`promptForDouble()` method returns a double, it is the second line that concerns me most. The error I get is

> "error: double cannot be dereferenced."

I assume what's going on is the variable needs to be the argument of the `Math` class methods, but I understand it could also have to do with the variable being a primitive type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abs` and `sqrt` aren't methods of `double` (which is a primitive, so it doesn't have any methods anyway - as noted in the error message you're getting), but static method of `Math` that take a `double` as an argument and return a `double` result:

```
double sqrtAbsOutput = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(sqrtAbsInput));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Great!

Answer (score 2):

`Math` class does not implement "builder pattern" (for efficiency reasons), but you can create your own Math class implementation which allows chaining.

Here is an example:

```
public class MathBuilder {
    private double value;

    public MathBuilder(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MathBuilder abs() {
        value = Math.abs(value);
        return this;
    }

    public MathBuilder sqrt() {
        value = Math.sqrt(value);
        return this;
    }

    // other builder-math methods...

    public double build() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
double result = new MathBuilder(-10).abs().sqrt().build();
```

Or with Java 8:

```
public class MathBuilder {
    private double value;

    public MathBuilder(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MathBuilder apply(DoubleUnaryOperator o) {
        value = o.applyAsDouble(value);
        return this;
    }

    public double build() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
double result = new MathBuilder(-10)
        .apply(Math::abs)
        .apply(Math::sqrt)
        .build();
```

Comment: This answer my question very literally. I hesitate to accept it because I won't be using this answer, despite it answering my question to the letter. *shrug* be careful what you wish for.

Comment: @KaariLandry no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this:

```
System.out.println(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(sqrtAbsInput)));
```